# re-arrange dataframe rows contents for keras cnn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, keras

I have a dataframe with shape of(60,) , i.e 60 rows `videos_df['videos'].shape : (60,)`

In each row there are different number of images (64*64) parsed from folders : `for i in range(len(videos_df)):
    print(videos_df['videos'][i].shape) 
(1778, 64, 64)
(1560, 64, 64)
(3759, 64, 64)
(4243, 64, 64)
.....`

The rows that contains video frames are different in length according to video length , How can I use these video frames in keras , where each video row if df should have it is own class label ?

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lchvu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model need the shape of inputs is `(?,64,64,1)`. But the shape of your input data is `(40,)`, and each dimension is `(?,64,64)`. So you need `np.concatenate` and `np.newaxis`.

```
# shape= (?,64,64,1)
x_train = np.concatenate(x_train,axis=0)[:,:,:, np.newaxis]
y_train = np.concatenate(y_train,axis=0)
x_test = np.concatenate(x_test,axis=0)[:,:,:, np.newaxis]
y_test = np.concatenate(y_test,axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank for help @giser_yugang, When I run the code , it collects all the x_train and y_train rows into single entry e.g for x_train  : (11987264, 64, 1, 1) , I think it should concatenate each dataframe row into (? , 64,64,1 ) , how to achieve this ?

Comment: @mela The result of the above code is `(?,64,64,1)` on my machine. Did you do anything else?

Comment: The result is like this : x_train: (11987264, 64, 1, 1)
y_train: (40,)
x_test : (8289280, 64, 1, 1)
y_test : (40,)  , is  y_train and y_test is correct with  x_train and x_test ?

Comment: The shape is correct now , I think when I run multiple time the shape changes , but now I'm getting this error :      ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 187301 input samples and 40 target samples.

Comment: @mela `expected dense_4 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)` shows that your `y_train` does not match expected output of A model. Maybe you need 
do one-hot on `y_train`. `Found 187301 input samples and 40 target samples` shows that `x_train` does not match `y_train`. Your `x_train` have 187301 input samples but `y_train` have 40 samples. Did you really execute my code? This  problem should not arise.

Comment: I have updated the question , please have a look , I think the problem is with the shapes . I think each dataframe row should have a corresponding target

Comment: @mela Why do you use `y_train = np.concatenate([y_train],axis=0)` instead of `y_train = np.concatenate(y_train,axis=0)`?

Comment: @ giser_yugang  , please see updated question , I think your solution is not doing what i mean